# What do you call "-a" or any letter after hypen/dash (-) in Shell Scripting?

Tags: shell, unix

Below is the code in my project I am trying to understand. Anyone can interpret what is it called? (-s and -a)

```
if [***-s*** $A ***-a -s*** $B] 

then ..

else ..

fi
```

Also, Is there a dictionary wherein all of - is listed and its use?

Google search does not exactly match the information I need. Since I don't know what's called. Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `man [` for start.

Comment: Unix and Unix-like systems (like Linux or macOS) usually comes with *manual pages*. Type e.g. `man test` in a shell, and read about the `test` command. And `[` is an alias for `test`.

Comment: I'm calling them flags.

Comment: POSIX standard calls these _primaries_ of the `test` command (`[` is an alias for the command), documented e.g. [in the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). It's the term [Bash Guide for Beginners](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) uses as well.

Comment: And what they are called? They could be called options, flags, modifiers, or just plain command-line arguments.

Comment: In general, the strings passed to the command are called _arguments_, perhaps historically established when the C language was invented, and Kernighan and Ritchie used the variable name `argv` (argument vector) for the array holding those strings. Those arguments with a leading dash describe program options and are therefore often called _option arguments_.  Your _test_ command is a bit unusual however, since those `-s` and `-a` are not semantically used as an option argument. You can call them just _arguments for the `test` command_.

Comment: @delightfulmemento What POSIX calls primaries are the primary expressions like `-f <path>`, in which `-f` is the operator.  See where it says that a primary's syntax is *-primary_operator primary_operand*. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for conditional expressions. Assuming you are using bash, you can look at the section [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) of the Bash Reference Manual.

```
-a file
True if file exists.

-b file
True if file exists and is a block special file.

-c file
True if file exists and is a character special file.

-d file
True if file exists and is a directory.

-e file
True if file exists.

-f file
True if file exists and is a regular file.

-g file
True if file exists and its set-group-id bit is set.

-h file
True if file exists and is a symbolic link.

-k file
True if file exists and its "sticky" bit is set.

[...]
```

See the documentation cited above for the full list.

Comment: +1. If not using Bash specifically, then the POSIX spec may be of use: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Hello, yes I am using bash. Thanks for the manual. I am going thru it right now. I hope you don't mind clarify what does socket mean for -s

Comment: For `-S` the term socket refers to [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

Comment: But `-s` means `True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.`

Answer (score 2):

In the context of `[ ... ]` they are called ***operators***.

The command `[ -s "$A" -a -s "$B" ]` is "true" if file A has non-zero size AND file B has non-zero size.

Always quote your variables in general, but particularly inside `[ ... ]`

---

> Also, Is there a dictionary wherein all of - is listed and its use?

At a bash prompt, enter `help test`.

---

The double bracket `[[ ... ]]` provides additional operators, see `help [[`